# RegExpr advice needed - remove all chars from string except of numbers (0-9) and "/"

Tags: javascript, regex

I need some advice using the RegExp Object.

It should only return numbers and the character "/" from the variable val ... I'm not experienced in the RegExp Object - this is what I got so far:

```
var val = $('.gallerystatus input').val();

var regExpr = new RegExp("^\d*\.?\d*$");

$('.gallerystatus input').val(  only 0-9 and "/"  );
```

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: This is a little unclear about exactly what you want it to return.  Do you want it to return individual numbers, and the "/" character?  Or do you want it to just filter out any other character and return the string with only 0-9 and '/' present?

Comment: 2 case: filter out any other character and return the string with only 0-9 and '/' present!

Comment: like in the description, dont look at the "^\d*\.?\d*$" ... maybe its just bullshit :-)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
value = value.replace(/[^\/\d]/g,'');
```

The trick is the `^` symbol. When it's inside a `[]` character class, the `^` is a negation operator for the class.

So in this example, the `[]` class is matching every character except slash and digits.

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/5gMNg/

Comment: just perfect! nice answer! have to wait 5min to vote it as the solving one :-)

Comment: Also, you didn't mention how important the 'g' flag is here on the end.  If you don't have it there, it will only replace the first occurrence of the matched group.

Comment: when we have a string contain number like this 10.5 it return 105 and that is wrong

Comment: @YounesZaidi - the question didn't ask for dots, so I didn't include it. It would be easy enough to add them though.