# How to split &plusmn; 3% ? ±3%

Tags: javascript, split

I have the value ± 3%  ±3%. I need to select only the number. How to split and select only number.

```
 var str = document.getElementById("band4tolerance");
 var b4d4 = str.options[str].value; 
alert("b4d4===>"+b4d4);
```

I get b4d4 = ±3% I need to take only numeric 3. How do i proceed?

Comment: Please show some code to illustrate what you are doing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing everything except numbers in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18099653/removing-everything-except-numbers-in-a-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below will return an array of all the digits in the value.

```
var value = 'HI! ± 333.3% The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog 3.0 times.';
var regex = /\d+\.?\d*/g;
var found = value.match(regex);

console.log(found); // ["333.3", "3.0"]
```